# Merging a historic picture with a current

Tags: python, image, opencv, merge, computer-vision

I have the following problem I am stuck on. I have two pictures of a wall. One is a historical photo from around 1900 and the other one is a current picture:

[image: Historic Photography]

[image: Current Picture]

I have a lot of polygon annotations on the current picture, which I would like to show on the historic photo, that is why I would like to merge the historic photo into the current picture while keeping the current picture as it is.

So far, I tried to solve this by finding corresponding points in both pictures with SIFT and then using cv2.findFundamentalMat. I then use cv2.stereoRectifyUncalibrated to get the homography matrices for each image. Finally I use cv2.warpPerspective to rectify.

The results are not convincing. My guess is, that this is due to a lens distortion, which is even visible by comparing both pictures to each other.

How can I solve this problem? Would solving the lens distortion help solving the problem? If so, how could I do that?